# Reading data from multiple tables (VB)

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqldatareader

I'm trying to read data in Visual Studio from multiple tables.

How do you read data from different tables? Do I have to create

- a separate connection,
- a separate command,
- a separate DataReader for each SELECT?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tables have a link then you JOIN them in the database engine first.

```
SELECT
   O.Col1, C.Col2, ...
FROM
   Orders O
   JOIN
   Customers C ON O.CustomerID = C.Customer
WHERE
    ...
```

If they are not to be JOINed, you can issue multiple SELECTs in one call and iterate through several DataReaders. Or load a DataSet via a DataAdaptor

Answer (score 0):

Actually its about your sql string. You can use "joins" to join multiple tables. Let me show u an example code:

```
    String strConn = "Server = .\\SqlExpress;Database = Pubs;Integrated Security = SSPI;";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select a.*,b.LoginID From atable a inner Join asecondtable b On a.userID=b.LoginID", conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```